# failed connect to localhost with nc

Tags: 20.04, connection, localhost

Good evening,

I am trying to run the following command on Ubuntu 22:

```
nc -vv 127.0.1.1 1234
```

But console returns this error:

```
nc: connection to port 127.0.1.1 failed 1234 (tcp): connection refused
```

Do I have to enable or configure something before I can test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netcat is blind and it can listen exactly to what you indicating.
In your case, I think you will have to enable the service on the indicating host and port. Or just change the host or port of your already running service.

If you want to start a service on your **localhost** to listen for incoming connections you can use the `-l` flag.

```
nc -l 1234
```

Once the service is running at `localhost` and on port `1234`, you can use the `nc` command again to start listening.

```
nc -vv 127.0.0.1 1234
```

If you want to connect to a **different machine**, you will have to know the IP address and the port where the service is running and listening. And then you can use something like this.

```
nc -vv <IP address> <port number>
```